# JSON, Highcharts and Coldfusion json data

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts, coldfusion-11

I have been trying to make this work for sometime and its I cannot seem to find the solution to make this work.

I am able to output JSON with my coldfusion CFC without issue, not I am trying to use this JSON with Highcharts.js. I have verified that the JSON is valid but highcharts seems to have an issue because in the series data there is double quotes surrounding the data. I've looked everywhere for a solution and I cannot seem to find any help that can set me on the right path. If I remove the double quotes from around the array in the series.data the chart loads in fine but I get away from it being dynamic.

**Here is my JSON output from my CFC:**`

```
{
    "series": [{
        "data": "[[Date.UTC(2017,05,21),2.9],[Date.UTC(2017,05,28),2.9],[Date.UTC(2017,06,04),3.1],[Date.UTC(2017,06,11),2.9]]",
        "name": "ATC Main Pod A - B - C"
    }, {
        "data": "[[Date.UTC(2017,05,21),2.8],[Date.UTC(2017,05,28),2.6],[Date.UTC(2017,06,04),2.9],[Date.UTC(2017,06,11),2.9]]",
        "name": "ATC Mays (ACB Blue)"
    }, {
        "data": "[[Date.UTC(2017,05,21),2.4],[Date.UTC(2017,05,28),2.6],[Date.UTC(2017,06,04),3],[Date.UTC(2017,06,11),3.2]]",
        "name": "ATC Mays (ACB Purple)"
    }, {
        "data": "[[Date.UTC(2017,05,21),3.3],[Date.UTC(2017,05,28),3.3],[Date.UTC(2017,06,04),3.4],[Date.UTC(2017,06,11),3.3]]",
        "name": "ATC R10 Pod D"
    }, {
        "data": "[[Date.UTC(2017,05,21),3.3],[Date.UTC(2017,05,28),3.4],[Date.UTC(2017,06,04),2.8],[Date.UTC(2017,06,11),1.9]]",
        "name": "ATC TU Pod A - B"
    }, {
        "data": "[[Date.UTC(2017,05,21),2.9],[Date.UTC(2017,05,28),2.9],[Date.UTC(2017,06,04),3.1],[Date.UTC(2017,06,11),3.4]]",
        "name": "CTRC 1st Floor"
    }, {
        "data": "[[Date.UTC(2017,05,21),2.9],[Date.UTC(2017,05,28),3.3],[Date.UTC(2017,06,04),3.2],[Date.UTC(2017,06,11),2.3]]",
        "name": "CTRC 2nd Floor"
    }]
}
```

**Here is what my ajax call looks like:**

```
function loadChartData(c){
$.ajax({type: "POST", url: "CFCs/survey.cfc", data: {method:"results_RLU", CENTERID: c},dataType: 'json',success: function(data){
    options.series = data.series
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options)
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Any errors in javascript console if you hit F12?

Comment: Looks like your `data` property is itself a string, in JSON format. You'll have to go through them and call JSON.parse on those values.

Comment: @mkaatman, no errors in the console.

Comment: The right way to solve it is work on that back end to return it as an array instead of string. If you can't do that use the answer you got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a problem!

Simply iterate each item in the series and parse the data to valid JSON object.

Enjoy :)

```
function loadChartData(c){
$.ajax({type: "POST", url: "CFCs/survey.cfc", data: {method:"results_RLU", CENTERID: c},dataType: 'json',success: function(data){

    options.series = data.series.map(function(item) 
    {
       item.data = JSON.parse(item.data);

       return item;
    });

    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options)
    }
});
}
```

Comment: This is going to work, I need to change up my query a bit it doesn't like the way I have that field setup. '[Date.UTC('||to_char(THEWEEKOF,'yyyy,mm,dd') ||'),'||ROUND(AVG(RATING),1)||']' DATA